# Getting 401 - Unauthorized when developer tool (F12) is open in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, access-denied, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I am getting 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. When developer tool is opened in IE.

When it is not opened i can easily go through all my pages without any trouble. But whenever the developer tool i open and i try to go to the next page.. Access denied.

This only happens in Internet explorer. All other browsers works fine.
And we have to test it in IE with developer tool open, so we cannot just change browser.

I am using Internet Information services manager (IIS) for authentication.
The only authentication that is on is Anonymous authentication.

I have tried many different configuration on the server but nothing seems to works.

Do anyone have any ideas to why access is denied when developer tool is open in IE and how to fix? it?

Comment: It occurs when the authentication to Admin or Helpdesk portal fails, please try to disable the nonymous authentication and Windows Authentication is enabled.

Comment: When i just get a windows authentication prompt and i dont want that aswell. And that is without the developer tool open in IE. Remember it is only with developer tool open i am getting acces denied.